# how to loop laravel with() function?

Tags: php, laravel, relation

I have a problem, this my code:
I edit my quest.

//its still error because $x is an array.

```
$x = [$arr[0], $arr[1],$arr[2],$arr[3]];
```

return $this->with($x)->where('parent_id', '=', null)->get();

//its ok. but i want to looping $arr inside laravel with function.

```
return $this->with($arr[0], $arr[1],$arr[2],$arr[3])->where('parent_id', '=', null)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate array, and loop that:

```
$array = [
    [$child => function ($query) {
        $query->whereIn('id', $this->collectID);
    }],
    [$child . '.' . $child => function ($query) {
        $query->whereIn('id', $this->collectID);
    }],
    [$child . '.' . $child . '.' . $child => function ($query) {
        $query->whereIn('id', $this->collectID);
    }],
    [$child . '.' . $child . '.' . $child . '.' . $child => function ($query) {
        $query->whereIn('id', $this->collectID);
    }],
    [$child . '.' . $child . '.' . $child . '.' . $child . '.' . $child => function ($query) {
        $query->whereIn('id', $this->collectID);
    }]
];
// loop through $array, do what you need and than pass it to the with method below
return $this->with($array)->whereNull('parent_id')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still confused.

Comment: explain why, please.

Comment: i still can't loop inside with function , here is my code :         return $this->with(
            
            $arr[0], $arr[1],$arr[2],$arr[3]                                         

        )->where('parent_id', '=', null)->get();